# Преобразование массива в строку без null элементов

Tags: java, массивы

Есть класс с полями `name`, `description`, `String[] comments = new String[10]` и т.д.
Как переопределить метод `toString` таким образом, чтобы избавиться от `null` значений массива?

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "№: " + getId() + "; " +
            "Имя: " + getName() + "; " +
            "Описание: " + getDescription() + "; " +
            "Время создания: " + getCreate() + "; " +
            "Комментарии: " + Arrays.toString(getComments());
}
```

При текущей реализации получаем:

> №: 1482208198038; Имя: name; Описание: desc; Время создания: 10 01
>   2017 10:40:18; Комментарии: [comment, null, null, null, null, null,
>   null, null, null, null].

`ArrayList` не подходит.

Comment: ну если `getComments()` возвращает null. то тут ниче не поделаешь. можно просто удалить null-элементы из массива

Comment: getComments просто возвращает массив comments. У меня была идея вернуть новый созданный массив без null, но это надо сначала посчитать сколько будет ненулевых элементов, потом создать массив, и переписать в него ненулевые элементы. Думал можно проще как-то, arrayList не подходит по условию задачи.

Comment: Зачем их вам в toString()-то пихать? toString - это не метода сброса всей полезной информации, а просто строка с текстом, позволяющая идентифицировать объект.

Comment: В смысле ArrayList не подходит?

Comment: arrayList не подходит по условиям задачи. Не научили еще им пользоваться.
Так у меня в объекте массив комментариев. Для упрощенного вывода в методах например listOfBids (system.out.println(bid))
https://github.com/Sunseer/java-core/tree/master/chapter_002/src/main/java/ru/agrin/tracker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь стримами:

```
Arrays.stream(getComments())
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")
```

Comment: Может оказаться довольно жирно для toString

Comment: @Etki сложно тут что то лучше придумать. если запилить без stream'ов c использованием цикла, то это не сильно быстрее.

Comment: то это минимум на 4 + N вызовов меньше

Comment: jit умеет хорошо оптимизировать и инлайнить стримы, т.к. они довольно предсказуемы. накидал тест для замера моего примера и того что предложил @Barmaley получилось не сильно медленно, 7.3к ops/ms против 6.6k ops/ms https://gist.github.com/izebit/164ce41594fb570cea6ad618541c2dfb

Comment: Угу, а теперь посмотрите Тагира Валеева на джокере 2015. Оптимизировать-то может, но не обязан, тем более не в синтететических тестах, тем более что не везде одинаковый jit.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov с ответом Barmaley пока что рановато сравнивать, ибо там есть ошибки.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, а вы можете замерить производительность, если бы метод getComments() возвращал новый массив без null?

Comment: @Etki а где здесь синтетика, тест  приближен к тому как метод будет реально использоваться. Размер массива может быть слишком большой, но это сделано лишь для того, чтобы показать разницу между способами. Если там size будет 10 то отличие будет совсем мизерное.

Comment: @A.Grin глянь код, там использован, крайний случай,  когда нулей как раз и нет.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, я имел ввиду без использования stream api.

Comment: @A.Grin  я не понимаю чего вы хотите. в тесте есть замер для двух случаев, для for и для stream api.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, простите, туплю )

Comment: @A.Grin то есть список `ArrayList` вы ещё не "прошли", а Stream API - уже "прошли"?

Comment: @Regent, так вышло).

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov я немного был на эмоциях и поэтому мои комментарии были, кхм, несколько заряжены. Я хотел бы извиниться за это перед тем, как пойду дальше.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Теперь что касается синтетики. Если вы видели выступление Тагира, то он как раз разбирал этот случай. Все прекрасно инлайнится до тех пор, пока в стриме используются одни и те же типы: как только в метод начинают приходить разные типы, инлайнинг перестает работать, потому что он не знает, что ему придется инлайнить в следующий раз. Кроме того, в том же примере было показано, что компилятор начинает инлайнить "сверху", и поэтому если в юзер-коде заинлайнилось шесть методов, то(при условии MaxInlineLevel=9) на стримы остается только три.

Comment: Что касается самого бенчмарка, то он, как минимум, измеряет производительность генерации комментариев, а не кода. Я ей-богу в первый раз запустил JMH, но просто вынеся в `@Setup` создание массива с комментариями я добился четырех-пятикратного (!) увеличения throughput. Сами показатели, впрочем, остались примерно одинаковыми, но если предположить, что что-то съедает до 4/5 бенчмарка, то разница между оставшимся, естественно, будет нивелирована. Шипилев не просто так акцентирует внимание на том, что это непростая тема. Анализировать дальше, к сожалению, у меня нет времени, но

Comment: я готов согласиться с тем, что в этом синтетическом примере разница минимальна

Comment: @Etki  не заметил чтобы коменты были заряжены :) Дискуссия полезна, т.к. позволяет обмениваться мнениями и узнавать что то новое. Про MaxInlineLevel понятно. Про разные типы не совсем, если у нас есть массив строк, то очевидно, он им и останется. Тест неидеален, генерация массива занимает время, но а)размер массива фиксированный, б)генерация рандомных чисел думаю занимает фиксированное время в)оба теста используют один и тот же метод. Рискну предположить что и затраты на создание массива в обоих случаях будут примерно одинаковы=>в замере есть некоторая константа, которая на сравнение невлияет

Answer (score 1):

можно побороть таким методом:

```
private String toString(String[] strArray) {
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
      if(strArray[i]!=null) {
         if(k > 0)
           sb.append(", ");
         sb.append(strArray[i]);
         k++;
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Я не компилятор и даже не транслятор. Ответ написан на коленках, исправил опять на коленках

Comment: Это понятно. Но ответ либо верный, либо нет, независимо от того, на чем он написан. Можно, кстати, тип `k` сменить с `int` на `boolean`, но это уже дело вкуса.